# Tool to snap point to point in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, line-art, anchor-point

**Wondering if this exists in Illustrator.**
A tool that allows you to select an anchor point of an object and snap/move it on-top of another point. I cant think of how to do this and there doesn't seem to be any options for it. "Snap to point doesn't work?"

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

[image: Diagram showing further into snapping.]

*^Trying to get green point to snap to the red point.*

Comment: Enable smart guides use white arrow tool to drag the green point (yeah white arrow tool, dont use black)

Comment: If I understood the scenario correctly, Astute Graphic's Colliderscribe plugin should do it. Here's a little preview video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDtqeMzDiwk

Answer (score 1):

This feels trickier than it should be, especially when multiple objects are already on the destination point, but holding down the command|control key should bring success:

1. Select your green point
2. On Mac, hold down the Command key

   --or--

   On Windows, hold down the Control key
3. Slide it close the the destination point where you want to snap

You can see [Brandon Bledsoe's example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U759tLqPIYM) of how to do this on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

Following from @joojaa's answer use the Selection tool to select the whole object, then change to the direct selection tool and drag the point to the other point, there is no "smart guide" snapping to anchor point however the cursor will turn white when snapped.

Comment: Do you want to move the whole green object or just the green point? If you're moving the whole object there's no need to change to Direct Selection tool.

Comment: @Luciano this is not true, if you want to snap your cursor to a point reliably you need to use direct selection tool regardless of wether you want to move full object or not since the selection tool does not snap to points before dragging.

Comment: @joojaa yes it does: hover the cursor around the point until the smart guide label shows "anchor" then drag. I just did. Quite reliable.

Comment: @Luciano not for cases when the bounding box is close to the object border like here